# How do I share data between a GUI thread and a worker thread?

Tags: qt, qthread

My application is a simple message sender/receiver via TCP/IP with a GUI. Until now everything was one single thread, but I'd like to split the TCP/IP communication block and the GUI in separate threads. As I see it, I need a shared data structure (like a QQueue<QString>) to pass messages back and forth between the GUI thread and the TCP/IP thread.

The question is: where do I place this shared data structure? If I put it in either of the threads, how can the other thread access it? O is it better to use something of the likes of QSharedMemory?

Comment: You should use Qt's slots and signals mechanism to share data between the GUI thread and a worker thread.

Comment: Seconded... if you've got to signal that new data is available anyway (seems likely) then just use the signal itself to pass data. If it's a lot of data that you don't want to copy around too much, then maybe move to using a QMutex to control access to a shared list or queue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing data across Qt threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372301/sharing-data-across-qt-threads)

Comment: @darron: yes, I'd go for using a queue with a QMutex, but my doubt was where to declare it: if I declare it on one thread, can the other thread access it?

Comment: @alexrc function and data members of class instances, etc are completely usable from other threads... that's why you need the QMutex to prevent the bad things that can happen in both try to change stuff at the same time. If they have pointers to eachother, they can do whatever they like. Just add what you need to a thread class and provide public accessors for the other thread to call them.

Comment: Although... I'd mention again that depending on what you need to pass just using signals and slots would very possibly be easier/cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally create a global Singleton spin buffer which is a shared resource among the threads.

Have the "feed thread" (from your TCP/IP thread) put data on the buffer.
Have your "read thread" (From your GUI) pull data from the buffer.

Ensure you have the proper locks on both the "puts" and the "gets" to avoid race conditions and deadlocks.

John